# how to pass outlet context to nested route in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react router dom v6 how can I access the context in a nested route in the second child

```
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Parent/>}>
      <Route element={<Child/>}>
        <Route element={<ChildSecond/>}/>
      </Route>
    <Route> 
  </Routes>
```

I passed a context to Outlet in `Parent` Component I wanna access it in `ChildSecond` with out passing it again in `Child` component Outlet

expected code

Parent Component:

```
  const Parent = ()=>{
    const myContext = {someData:'hello world'}
    return <Outlet context={myContext}/>
  }
```

Child Component:

```
  const Child = ()=><Outlet/>
```

ChildSecond component

```
  import {useOutletContext} from 'react-router-dom'
  const ChildSecond = ()=>{
      const {someData} = useOutletContext()
      return <div>someData</div>
  }
```

Comment: Your first <Routes>, you called <Routs>, there's no path anywhere either.

Comment: the code is just an example of what I want it's not real code

Comment: I found this useful: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.4/hooks/use-outlet-context

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of v6.3.0. react-router's `useOutletContext()` [only works in the immediate child component](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext). If you really don't want to create your own context, you can easily forward the outlet context on like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Outlet, useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<Grandparent />}>
        <Route element={<Parent />}>
          <Route index element={<Child />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

function Grandparent() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Outlet context={{ someData: 'hello world' }} />
    </main>
  );
}

function Parent() {
  return <Outlet context={useOutletContext()} />;
}

function Child() {
  const { someData } = useOutletContext<{ someData: string }>();
  return <p>{someData}</p>;
}
```

Comment: Your answer saved my day man.

Answer (score 4):

You could define a context in the main component and provide it to the whole application:

```
export const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

...
// this works outside of RouteProvider at least
<GlobalContext.Provider
    value={{someData: 'hello world'}}>
    <Routes>
    <Route element={<Parent/>}>
      <Route element={<Child/>}>
        <Route element={<ChildSecond/>}/>
      </Route>
    <Route> 
  </Routes>
</GlobalContext.Provider>
```

Then retrieve the data anywhere in your application with:

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '/path/to/main/file';

...

const { someData } = useContext(GlobalContext);
```

Comment: that's is true I could do that but I was thinking since there is outlet context I don't need to wrap everything in context provider

Comment: @Revan99 Wrapping everything in a context provider is fine. IMO it is preferable to depends on a React hook rather than a React-Router hook